# Is it possible to save the Euler rotations as Quaternions without loss of data?

Tags: animation, quaternion

Long story short is that, that I made an animation using Euler rotation but during cleaning the graph I realized that the graph and the axis got mixed up, eg. x and y axis both gave more or less the same sort of rotation in the graph but in the 3D space on rotating along local axis I get a completely different type of rotation.
I usually do my animations with Quaternions, but this time, due to some issues I switched to Eulers without understanding how they work. Now I have a ton of animation data and a big mess cleaning up the graphs.

So my question is:

**Is it possible to save the Euler rotations as Quaternions without loss of data (visual data at least)?**

If that's not possible, then I should ask for the work around the graph editor so that the axis move according to the actual axis movements.

EDIT: I am presently using ZYX Euler rotation if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.79 there's an addon that works very well, called Quat/Euler rotation mode converter.

[image]

Comment: I want to thank you from the bottom of my heart! I have been going crazy thinking I had to redo all the hand animations. But your solution has worked just as i wanted! I tried to find a solution but had no idea that the solution already existed. Once again thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use default XYZ Euler and see if it helps.  And you can read > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles about the issue. I suppose it's the same as eg. RGB > BGR if you came across it.